# Joining 2 scopes laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to solve this for quite a while now. I want to join these two scopes from my Match Model:

```
public function scopeMainMatches($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', 'main');
}

public function scopeDotaMatches($query)
{
    return $query->join('leagues', function ($join) {
        $join->on('matches.league_id', '=', 'leagues.id')
            ->select('matches.*')
            ->where('leagues.type', '=', 'dota2')
            ->where('matches.type', '=', 'main');
    });
}
```

so basically, when I put in into join eloquent relationship it will be the same like this:

```
$query = DB::table('matches')
    ->join('leagues', 'leagues.id', '=', 'matches.league_id')
    ->select('matches.*')
    ->where('leagues.type', '=', 'dota2')
    ->get();
```

it works fine during the terminal check. but I need to connect 2 scopes for the Controller which looks like this:

```
$_matches = \App\Match::mainMatches()
    ->get()
    ->load('teamA', 'teamB')
    ->sortByDesc('schedule');
```

so when I try to connect mainMatches and dotaMatches, it doesn't show up on the matches. although when i run php artisan tinker, it returns the correct output, but it won't show up on the matches table.

```
$_matches = \App\Match::mainMatches()
    ->dotaMatches()
    ->get()
    ->load('teamA', 'teamB')
    ->sortByDesc('schedule');
```

any Ideas how to work on this? TYIA!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a complex nested join on scopeDotaMatches? Would a regular ->join('leagues', 'leagues.id', '=', 'matches.league_id') not do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to join two tables in just one scope here is the code:

```
 public function scopeMainMatches($query) {
    return $query->join('leagues','leagues.id','=','matches.league_id')->select('matches.*')->where('matches.type', 'main');
}
```